# python cx_Oracle memory leak

Tags: python, oracle, memory-leaks, cx-oracle

I have a problem with python cx_Oracle module

Repeated execution of the query via existing cursor ( possibly with 
        different parameters) causes huge memory leak

The stripped down example is attached.

Two  variants of query execution - mleak1 and mleak2,  with and  without prepare work the same way

The same problem exists in both python3 and python2

Reopening cursor after each query fixes the leak

Similar postgres version works fine

Is it a bug in cx_Oracle module?

The problem was reproduced on two completely different machines

```
logname@machine1(ubuntu_16.04):~> python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
    [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import cx_Oracle
    >>> cx_Oracle.__version__
    '6.0rc2'
    >>> 


[logname@machine2]$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (default, Oct 22 2016, 08:10:47) 
    [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import cx_Oracle
    >>> cx_Oracle.__version__
    '6.0'
>>> 


<code><pre>
###############################################################
import cx_Oracle
import psycopg2

sql_text="select 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from dual"
def mleak1(connect_string_ora ):
    with cx_Oracle.connect(connect_string_ora) as dbo:
        ora_cursor=dbo.cursor()


        for i in range(0,10000000):

            ora_cursor.execute(sql_text) 

            for r in ora_cursor:
                print (r) 

def mleak2(connect_string_ora ):
    with cx_Oracle.connect(connect_string_ora) as dbo:
        ora_cursor=dbo.cursor()

        ora_cursor.prepare(sql_text)
        for i in range(0,10000000):

            ora_cursor.execute(None) 

            for r in ora_cursor:
                print (r)

def no_mleak(connect_string_pg ):

    with psycopg2.connect(connect_string_pg) as dbp:
        pg_cursor=dbp.cursor()
        pg_cursor.execute("create table dual(f) as select 1")    #to mimics oracle sql text query

        for i in range(0,10000000):

            pg_cursor.execute(sql_text) 

            for r in pg_cursor:
                print (r) 

mleak1('scott/tiger')

#mleak2('scott/tiger')

#no_mleak('password=xxx dbname=mydb user=myuser')

</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect a bug in cx_Oracle, please log an issue here: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues.

I took a look at the code using your sample and indeed there is a memory leak, which I have just plugged. Thanks for reporting this!